# Compute the average app rating for the apps stored in the app_data_set variable

Tags: python

I want to calculate the sum of all the rating from the app_data_set list of lists and store it in rating_sum.

My code is adding up only the "row_1" rating 5 times  and storing it in rating_sum instead of adding rating from each row.

```
row_1 = ['Facebook', 0.0, '$', 2974676, 3.5]
row_2 = ['Instagram', 0.0, '$', 2161558, 4.5]
row_3 = ['Clash of Clans', 0.0, '$', 2130805, 4.5]
row_4 = ['Temple Run', 0.0, '$', 1724546, 4.5]
row_5 = ['Pandora - Music & Radio', 0.0, '$', 1126879, 4.0]
app_data_set = [row_1, row_2, row_3, row_4, row_5 ]
rating_sum = 0
for rating in app_data_set:
    rating = app_data_set[0][4]
    rating_sum = rating_sum + app_data_set[0][4]
    print(rating_sum)
```

I expect the output to be:

```
3.5 
8.0
12.5
16.5
20.5
```

Actual output is:

```
3.5
7.0
10.5
14.0
17.5
```

Comment: skip `rating = app_data_set[0][4];` change `rating_sum = rating_sum + rating[4]`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this loop instead:

```
for rating in app_data_set:
    rating_sum += rating[-1]
    print(rating_sum)
```

Which gives:

```
3.5
8.0
12.5
17.0
21.0
```

(P.S. your output is wrong, mine should be correct, do the math)

Answer (score -1):

```
rating_sum=0
for rating in app_data_set:
    rating_sum += rating[-2]
    print(rating_sum)
```

its sum of (total no of reviews ) is a different column in the table.

Comment: Please format your code and tell us what the code does.